Install Visual Studio 2022 without access to powershell
I'm trying to update Visual Studio 2022 to include .NET 9, but my organization does not allow access to PowerShell. I noticed during the upgrade installer needs access to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.TestPowerShell.ps1 and vcredistinstall.ps1 and I don't have access to allow it.
I tried installing latest c++ redist, but the installer still gets stuck here. Is there a way to bypass this?
